# How should I explain UML class diagram?

Tags: uml

I have created a design using class diagram. However I was asked to give some explanation on the class diagram.

IMO, class diagram is fairly. For example, if a class is labeled as "Cat", am I going to explain, this "Cat" class represents "Cat"?

What is the best way to explain UML class diagram?

Comment: Who is asking you? What does he want to know?

Comment: my supervisor was asking me. I think he is going to use it to explain it to his client.

Comment: Your haven't provided sufficient information to get an answer. There can be infinite number of classes or diagrams, how do you expect someone to tell you anything without knowing some specific information? Describing a particular class diagram requires a lot of knowledge, domain knowledge etc.

Comment: Yes you are right.
However I was wondering what items I need to cover, like a check list. And do you explain it along with sequence diagram?>

Answer (score 4):

saying class `Cat` represents cats is one thing you can do, which is maybe not very exciting, though. More interesting to explain might be: associations, abstract classes, interfaces, inheritances, etc. is there any design pattern you are using? maybe explain them.

Comment: I have Boundary (UI / API), Control (Logic), Entity (Domain). I color coded them, e.g. entity classes are pink color, control classes are blue color etc. However I find interfaces, abstract classes etc, is quite obvious from the class diagram. I didn't use any design patterns.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this will help!

Suppose you have to explain this class diagram to your client in lieu your manager will. Just think how you will define all the responsibilities of each class present in that diagram. Give one-liner definition of its properties, methods, parent and child classes etc (go in bit more details when needed as well).

Define what would be the flow and how one class will link to another one. 
For example:

Is your class '**cat**' has any association with class **Animal** or interface **IAnimal**. You can think more of it and go better.

Answer (score 0):

whatever the type of uml diagram, you should always add some explanantions in natural language.

at least explain some key aspects of the solution : this has a reference to this
this inherits from this class and do not need to override this operation.